# How to run XCode 8 project on IOS 11

Tags: ios, xcode

I know there are lots of questions like mine but they didnt solve my problem.

I had xcode 8 and the system automatically forced to upgrade to 9.

After that I get lots of error when compiling project in xcode 9 and because of my rush I just need to prepare a new version using xcode 8 for ios 11.

After reinstalling Xcode 8.3.3 again, I dont see xcode 8 in the list of applications ( there is only xcode which is 9 ) but when opening project with "open with" I can choose xcode 8.

After opening project in xcode 8, ios 11 is not in the list of "ios development target" even after copying "developerDiskImage" for ios 11 in this folder:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

Its strange also that why I dont have :

/Applications/Xcode8.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: You cannot run iOS 11 in Xcode 8 (without maybe hacking around a bit, not recommended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 8 can't run with iOS 11 (only Xcode 9+).

But wait! There's a way; build an IPA and install it manually with iTunes to the device with iOS 11. But you won't have debug.

Comment: Its a great Idea, but when I run the installed app using IPA, it crashes in the middle, is there anything to set to help

Comment: In middle of installation or in middle of using the app?

Comment: No when running , is there any way to compile xcode 8 project in xcode 9 in order to run in ios 11 without getting compile error and without updating pods, I tried to change command line tools to xcode 8.3.3 instead of 9 also changed switch language version to 3.2 but didnt work

Comment: I updated Xcode 8 projects to Xcode 9 projects without any problem. Just use the EDIT -> CONVERT -> Current Swift syntax. Then check everything is fine. I believe u will have to pod instal again (not sure).

Also did from 9 to 8. Have to disable the safe area plus convert to swift 3.2

Comment: Also did that run without any problem in Xcode 8 and iOS 10? You can also downgrade your device iOS version to 10.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes It was working fine using xcode 8 on ios 10 . I already tried to convert as you mentioned using convert tools but I get lots of new errors in the pods that has been used. I even updated them but still having problem.I thought there may be a simpler solution except spending lots of time at this point

Comment: Oh yes! After doing the convert, do pod install. That will remove tons of errors. Then check code by hand.